# Why are the values in my allEffects graph wrong?

Tags: r, mixed-models, emmeans

I am currently working on my thesis project and for some reason when I use allEffects I keep getting the wrong graph. I'm really not sure why is this the case. Does anyone have any solutions on how to fix that? And if not how else can I make the graph without allEffects? I need to have both lines in the same graph.

This is just the graph that separated both genders:

[image: This is just the graph that separated both genders.]

These are the values that are supposedly estimated in the graphs, however the values differ and that's what's confusing me.

[image: These are the values that are supposedly estimated in the graphs, however the values differ and that's what's confusing me.]

This is the kind of a graph I need to get in the end.

[image: This is the kind of a graph I need to get in the end.]

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! We will be better able to answer the question if you can create a reproducible example of the problem. Can you copy the code used to fit the model and make the plots, as well as the output of calling `dput()` on your data? It doesn't need to be all your data, but if you can fit the same model on a subset and get the same problem, I will look into this tomorrow. More information on a reproducible example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you please take your `emmeans` (non-graphical) output and replace the screenshot with code-formatted text?  Text is searchable and accessible to people with screen readers ...

Comment: It seems that `emmeans::emmip(model.qlq.g, geslacht ~ timepoint, CIs = TRUE)` would produce the graph you want. But that doesn't explain why allEffexts gives different results.